# Matlab ignores my if condition

Tags: matlab, if-statement

still having troubles with the way Matlab works...

I set up a model comprised of differential equations, which are called by the ode45 solver. The ode45 solver itself passes a function of v0 to the system.

This is my model:

```
%chemostat model, based on:
%DCc=-v0*Cc/V + umax*Cs*Cc/(Ks+Cs)-rd -->Change of cell concentration over time
%Dcs=(v0/V)*(Cs0-Cs) - Cc*(Ys*umax*Cs/(Ks+Cs)-m) -->Change of substrate concentration over time

function dydt=sys(t,y,v0,V,umax,Ks,rd,Cs0,Ys,m)
 dydt=[-(v0(t,y)/V)*y(1)+(umax*y(1)*y(2))/(Ks+y(2))-rd; 
       (v0(t,y)/V)*(Cs0-y(2))-(Ys*umax*y(2)*y(1))/(Ks+y(2))];
```

This is my function of v0:
    `

```
    function v0 = funV0( t,y )
    persistent i
    if isempty(i)
        i=0;
    end

    if y(1) > 5 || i==1
        v0=20
        v0 = 20+200*t % As an example, if [Y1] > 5, then set v0 = [Y2]
        i=1
    else 
        v0=0
        i=0
    end
end
```

The model works fine if I just pass:

```
v0=20
v0=v0+200*t
```

However, the above code with the if conditions does not work. Even though y(1) initially is 1 (and increases slowly over time) the if condition is ignored.

Can somebody explain this behavior and maybe point out a solution?

Thanks in advance and special thanks again to [Rollen D'Souza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4611899/rollen-dsouza) who helped me with the code in the first place.

Comment: are you using the `funV0`? I don't see it being called.

Comment: `funV0` returns `v0`. I think you are treating `v0` like a function when it is in fact a double.

Comment: @Memming:
The funV0 gets called by the ode45:
[t,y]=ode45(@systemEquations2, [0 5],[Cc0 Cs0],[],@funV0, V,umax,Ks,rd,Cs0,Ys,m);

Comment: @2cents:
could you elaborate a litte more? Not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: Sorry, but it seems too many things can go wrong here you should try the [debugger](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/debugging-code.html?refresh=true). Set a breakpoint right before the if statement and make sure the conditions are met.

Comment: Where do you set i?  Otherwise, it is going to be set to 0.

Comment: @Patrik: Thank you very much for the hint regarding the debugger, this helped very much in actually understanding my code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last getting back to this, sorry to all who contributed! Thank you all, though. All suggestions helped me find the correct direction.

So, I thought MatLab ignored my if-statement. After using the debugger as suggested by patrik, it turned out this was wrong. The function was called properly and also the if-statement was entered correctly.

I encountered three issues that were causing problems:

- Variable i was defined as "persistent". This requires a clearing of the function for every new run. Something I didn't know at the time I posted the question and what led to strange results.
- in the if statement it has to be y(1,1) instead of y(1)
- in my original code v0 is dependent on t. I wanted v0 to be dependent on t minus the time point when y(1,1) was greater than the threshold the first time.

Additionally one more thing caused me to question the code:
The ode-solver jumps back at some time points when y(1,1) is first greater than the threshold. This led to negative values of v0, skewing the model. This was solved by additional lines of code in the v0 function.

Below you find the updated code:

Differential equations:

```
%chemostat model, based on:
%DCc=-v0*Cc/V + umax*Cs*Cc/(Ks+Cs)-rd
%Dcs=(v0/V)*(Cs0-Cs) - Cc*(Ys*umax*Cs/(Ks+Cs)-m)
function dydt=systemEquations(t,y,funV0,V,umax,Ks,rd,Cs0,Ys,m)

        v=funV0(t,y);          
           dydt=[-(v/V)*y(1)+(umax*y(1)*y(2))/(Ks+y(2))-rd; 
           (v/V)*(Cs0-y(2))-(Ys*umax*y(2)*y(1))/(Ks+y(2))];
end
```

Function of v0:

```
function v0 = funV0( t,y )

    persistent i %has to be persistent to be carried over for the next function call
    persistent j %has to be persistent to be carried over for the next function call

    if isempty(i) %for initial assignment of i
        i=0;
    end

    if y(1,1) > 5.00 || i==1 %y(1,1) reads value if y-matrix
        if isempty(j) %initial assignment of j, reads t value from system equations
            j=t
        end

       v0=20   
       a=t-j
       v0=v0+a*2000
           if v0<0 %ode-solver jumps to time points before Cc>threshold --> negative values for v0 --> skews model
            v0=0
           end
        i=1
    else 
        v0=0
        i=0
    end
end
```

Calling code:

```
%ODE solver for model
%first brackets determine timespan (e.g. [0 20] means hour 0 to 20)
[t,y]=ode23(@systemEquations, [0 5],[Cc0 Cs0],[],@funV0,V,umax,Ks,rd,Cs0,Ys,m);

%plotting
plot(t,y);

%clearing of persistent variables
clear funV0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems here.

1. You are treating `v0` as a function when it is a scalar
2. Your conditions for the if statement are not met

**Function vs Scalar**

When you define `function v0 = funV0( t,y )` what this statement means is that the function call `funV0(t,y)` returns the value `v0`.

In the `funV0` function, you set `v0` to be either `v0 = 20+200*t` or `v0=0` depending on a condition. Unless, `t` is a vector or a matrix, `v0` will be a scalar value.

In your `sys` function, you pass in `v0`. I'm assuming this refers to the same value as above. Then you do `v0(t,y)`. If `v0` were a matrix, this would retrieve the element at (t,y). However, it will not call the function `funV0(t,y)` which is what I think you want to do.

Instead of `v0(t,y)`, you should use the function call `funV0(t,y)`.

**If statement conditions**

This is the behavior that I observed for your `funV0` function.

You describe that y(1) is initially 1, so I set `y=1` to test your function.

I called funV0(1, 1) and set a breakpoint, so that I could walk through the code. Here's what happened.

```
function v0 = funV0( t,y )
    % breakpoint here

    %i is initialized to []
    persistent i

    % enter this if statement
    if isempty(i)
        i=0; % i is now 0
    end

    %Here y(1)==1 and i==0 so we skip the if statement and enter the else statement
    if y(1) > 5 || i==1
        v0=20
        v0 = 20+200*t
        i=1
    else 
        % We end up here
        v0=0 
        i=0
    end
end
```

At the end of the function, `v0` is returned with a value of 0.

If I call the function again with, `funV0(1, 6)`, I will enter the if statement because `y(1)>5`.

If you want to enter the if statement when `y(1)==1`, you should change the condition of the if statement. As it stands, the if statement is not entered because the conditions are not met.

Comment: Hi Cecilia, thank you for your answer and I'm so sorry for not getting back to  you earlier... Was stuck with other projects :/
the points you brought up are valid. However, when using the debugger it turned out that the v0 being passed as a scalar is not a problem. Also, I used your code and the result is the same.
I will post an update shortly.
Cheers

Comment: I posted an answer that shows the solution to my problem. In my case passing v0 as a scalar wasn't a problem. Since there is only one v0 for every point in time. Thanks though for your answer, helped me understand functions in Matlab a little better =)